# How do I pass multiple models into a view?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am easily and successfully passing a single model into a view in one of my express routes like this:

```
exports.locations = function(req, res){
    Location.find(function(err, results) {
        res.render('locations', { title: 'Locations', locations: results });
    });
};
```

I have another route where I need to pass 2 result sets into the view, how do I do that? I have tried doing this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
exports.locationdetail = function(req, res) {
    var packages = Package.find();
    Location.findById(req.params.id, function(err, result) {
        res.render('location-detail', { title: 'Location Details', location: result, packages: packages });
    });
};
```

**Edit 1**

The error I am getting is:

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

My model looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
   ,Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PackageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    name: String,
    prev_package: String,
    featured: Boolean,
    services: Array
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Package', PackageSchema);
```

And I am using this model in another view, and everything is working like a champ.

Comment: @hexacyanide I just updated my question with some of the info that you are looking for. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

```
var mongoOp     =   require("./models/mongo");
var async = require('async');

router.get("/",function(req,res){
    var locals = {};
    var userId = req.params.userId;
    async.parallel([
        //Load user data using Mangoose Model 
        function(callback) {
             mongoOp.User.find({},function(err,user){
                if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.user = user;
                callback();
            });
        },
        //Load posts data using Mangoose Model
        function(callback) {
                mongoOp.Post.find({},function(err,posts){
               if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.posts = posts;
                callback();
            });
        }
    ], function(err) { //This function gets called after the two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
        if (err) return next(err); //If an error occurred, we let express handle it by calling the `next` function
        //Here `locals` will be an object with `user` and `posts` keys
        //Example: `locals = {user: ..., posts: [...]}`


         res.render('index.ejs', {quotes: locals.user,userdata: locals.posts})
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like this was another asynchronous "gotcha". Putting this into a nested callback did the trick:

```
exports.locationdetail = function(req, res) {
    Location.findById(req.params.id, function(err, result) {
        Package.find(function (err, results) {
            res.render('location-detail', { title: 'Location Details', location: result, packages: results });
        });
    });
};
```